# Nested Repeater expand/collaps using JQuery not working

Tags: jquery

two level nested repeater
example of result

Skill Category 1
  Skill 1
  Skill 2
  Skill 3
Skill Category 2
  Skill 1
  Skill 2

```
and here is my Jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".expandhideContents").hide();


        $(".expandhideHeader").click(function()
        {
            $(this).next(".expandhideContents").slideToggle("fast"); 

        });
    });
```

my problem is that when i click the Skill Category 1, only one item inside of child repeater toggled, how can i make all item in the category i click expand or collaps?

Here is my html code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSkillCategory" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="expandhideHeader">
            <td width="500px"> 
                <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="skillTypeName" runat="server" Text= <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SkillTypeName") %>></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
                <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSkills" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"  >
                    <ItemTemplate >

                        <tr class="expandhideContents">
                        <td ><div class="gbl-FormField candidate-Skills" >
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSkillID" runat="server" Value=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SkillID") %> />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSkill" runat="server" Text= <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SkillName") %> /></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="gbl-TextBoxField"><asp:TextBox ID="txtMonthsExperience" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox><span class="gbl-FormValidator">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revMonthsExperience" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Value must be a whole number." ControlToValidate="txtMonthsExperience" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^\d+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater> 


         </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: can you post your html please? you need to post html in a Code sample block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### use `.nextUntil()` with your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/r2S33/

i suppose you have this kind of html structure:

```
<div class='expandhideHeader'>Skill page category 1</div>
    <div class='expandhideContents'>Skill 1</div>
    <div class='expandhideContents'>Skill 2</div>
    <div class='expandhideContents'>Skill 3</div>
<div class='expandhideHeader'>Skill page category 1</div>
    <div class='expandhideContents'>Skill 1</div>
    <div class='expandhideContents'>Skill 2</div>
    <div class='expandhideContents'>Skill 3</div>
```

so jQuery should be this:

```
$(".expandhideHeader").click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.expandhideHeader').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: kinda but instead of <div> i use <tr> and <td>s  and i had tried .nextUntil, it gave me this error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: can you tell which version of jQuery are you using.

Comment: OH yup this `.nextUntil()` was added in `1.4+`

Comment: i change to 1.9.1 now , but it still giving me same error msg

Comment: found the problem. in my page some there is another jquery reference and it is looking up for 1.3.2 again. it work now Thxxx~!!!